# Why beaglebone black uboot is configured to CONFIG_SYS_CPU="armv7". When bbb is armv8?

Tags: assembly, beagleboneblack, u-boot, armv7, armv8

Looking into .config file after configuring uboot for bbb using

make am335x_boneblack_defconfig

It shows:-

```
CONFIG_SYS_ARCH="arm"
CONFIG_SYS_CPU="armv7"
CONFIG_SYS_SOC="am33xx"
CONFIG_SYS_VENDOR="ti"
CONFIG_SYS_BOARD="am335x"
CONFIG_SYS_CONFIG_NAME="am335x_evm"
```

Why uboot for bbb is configured to armv7 as it is armv8 ?

I am trying to explore bootloaders. I am trying to write a new bootloader.
So a/c to above configuration, bootloader for armv7 should work fine for armv8 ?

I am confused , as it is armv8 which supports both aarch32 and aarch64 execution states.
If it is in AArch64 , then it has different instruction set.

In what mode the processor configuration just before loading  uboot ?

Please let me know if this is not the correct forum to ask.

Comment: This could be a good reference:
https://community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/arm-fundamentals-introduction-to-understanding-arm-processors?CommentId=1a52d8d1-acb8-4ef5-80c6-932387f41d7c

Answer (score 2):

The Beaglebone Black ships with an SoC that is based on the ARM Cortex-A8, which is an ARMv7 CPU core.

Comment: Yup.. My Bad.
BBB is Cortex-A8 which is whose architecture is ARMv7-A (32bit)